# How to set HTTP headers when using PhoneGap's FileTransfer().download()?

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to set HTTP headers when calling the download() method of the FileTransfer class?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a little bit about why you need this? I will mention why I think this is needed: in iOS6, XHR seems to be cached, so I would like to set caching to false. See this post: [https://groups.google.com/d/topic/phonegap/3zPQZXYCVHA/discussion].

Comment: See this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-861

Comment: Hey, I needed this because I wanted to download a file if it changed since a given timestamp set by If-Modified-Since header.

Comment: Nice - I can find a need for using that header as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the [mentioned bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-861) is now resolved - which means that the headers can be set with the latest version of PhoneGap.